# Prioritizing modifiers between different objects

Tags: modifiers, objects

I know I can prioritize modifiers in an object to decide which modifier will be computed before of another and viceversa, but can I prioritize modifiers between multiple objects?
For example, imagine we have two objects called A and B, they both have 2 modifiers, Am1; Am2; Bm1; Bm2. Can I prioritize them so that the computation order is the following: Am1 - Bm1 - Am2 - Bm2 ?
If not, can I at least prioritize one object on another, so that all the modifiers of an object are computed before of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

If a modifier (e.g. Am1) takes another object (B) as input, it will use the result of all modifiers applied to that object (i.e. it will depend on Bm1 and Bm2).

If you need a modifier on one object that only uses some of the modifiers on another (e.g B + Bm1) then you need to make a copy of that object with only the modifiers you need.

If you make the copy using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> rather than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then both objects will share the same mesh, so any edits on one will update the other.

Comment: Modifiers cannot be applied onto linked objects tho, I guess there's no way to make it animate, unless using Python.

Comment: Why would you need to apply the modifier to animate? Normally modifiers used in animation arent applied. Only when used for modelling is it common to apply them

Comment: Yes but if I would need to do a copy of the object to split the modifiers, I would need to apply it frame by frame no?
Example:
A has the modifier "Boolean" with Difference on C. B is a moving cube which overlaps A and moves away from A, having the modifiers "Boolean" with 'Intersect' on A, and "Wireframe". Then I have C which moves at the same position of A.

Comment: "I guess there's no way to make it animate" - to make what? You should describe in detail exactly what you want to do if you want to get an answer for your specific situation. Don't forget you can use all sorts of constraints and parenting, so you can have multiple objects interacting that are generated from the same linked geometry and you can have hidden copies just for use in modifiers belonging to other objects.